# Variable Storage - JDBC request in Jmeter

Tags: sql, variables, jdbc, jmeter

I have the following problem:

When adding a JDBC Request, query type "Select Statement", I add a variable name, but it doesn't save successfully.

Could anyone tell the reason?

Code below and print below.

Script to select:

```
USE ${DATABASE};

Declare @ID_SOLICITACAO_RSP as int
Declare @NM_ARQUIVO_RET as varchar (50)
set @ID_SOLICITACAO_RSP =
(
SELECT
VLR_SEQUENCIA
FROM
TBJD_SEQUENCIA
WHERE
CD_NEGOCIO = 'JDCTC'
AND CD_OBJETO = 'IDSOLIC'
)

SET @NM_ARQUIVO_RET =
(
SELECT substring(cat.nm_arqv, len(cat.nm_arqv)-30, 31) + '_RET.XML'
FROM TBJDCTCPRO_SOLIC_ARQV_TRANS SAT
JOIN TBJDCTCCIP_ARQV_TRANS CAT ON (SAT.ID_ARQV_TRANS = CAT.ID_ARQV_TRANS)
JOIN TBJDCTCPRO_SOLIC SOL ON (SOL.ID_SOLICITACAO = SAT.ID_SOLICITACAO)
WHERE SAT.ID_SOLICITACAO = @ID_SOLICITACAO_RSP
AND CAT.TP_ARQV IN ('ACTC101', 'ACTC201', 'ACTC301', 'ACTC401', 'ACTC501', 'ACTC601', 'ACTC701', 'ACTC801', 'ACTC851')
)

PRINT @NM_ARQUIVO_RET;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWh3c.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot because on JDBC level it's not possible to execute Select statement which calls [Statement.executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) under the hood which doesn't produce a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

So you need to transform your query to something like:

```
SELECT substring(cat.nm_arqv, len(cat.nm_arqv) - 30, 31) + '_RET.XML'
FROM TBJDCTCPRO_SOLIC_ARQV_TRANS SAT
         JOIN TBJDCTCCIP_ARQV_TRANS CAT ON (SAT.ID_ARQV_TRANS = CAT.ID_ARQV_TRANS)
         JOIN TBJDCTCPRO_SOLIC SOL ON (SOL.ID_SOLICITACAO = SAT.ID_SOLICITACAO)
WHERE SAT.ID_SOLICITACAO = (
    SELECT VLR_SEQUENCIA
    FROM TBJD_SEQUENCIA
    WHERE CD_NEGOCIO = 'JDCTC'
      AND CD_OBJETO = 'IDSOLIC'
)
  AND CAT.TP_ARQV IN ('ACTC101', 'ACTC201', 'ACTC301', 'ACTC401', 'ACTC501', 'ACTC601', 'ACTC701', 'ACTC801', 'ACTC851')
```

so it would issue single Select statement which would return a result.

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: Dmitri, it worked, but partially!

It's returning me [{ and ]} at the end.

Example:
[{=ACTC101_04358798_20220418_00012_RET.XML}]

Can I remove this in the script?

Comment: Put your `NM_ARQUIVO_RET` 1 line up in the JDBC Request sampler (to "Nomes das variaveis") and refer it as `${NM_ARQUIVO_RET_1}` where required. More information: [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) and [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: I achieved!!
Thank you very much!!!! =)